# Checking a list against keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, comparison

very new to python here, and this question seems similar to a few others asked on here, but varies in other ways.

I would like to check if a string from a list I created appears in the key values from a dictionary I created. I would like to use a for loop to print one message for the values that match the dictionary and list, and another message for the values that are in the list but not in the dictionary.

For example

`class_mates = ['Peter','Susan','Jen','Jeff','Niel','Sharon','Adam']`

```
respondents = {
'jeff':'python'
'susan':'ruby'
'niel':'c'
'peter':'python'
}
```

1. I purposefully made the respondents lower case, because ideally included in the answer would be some way to use a function, perhaps lower(), to make the values non_case sensitive.
2. I would like to use a for loop but am open to learning a better way. My output ideally would be something like,

```
Thanks for taking the poll Peter.
Thanks for taking the poll Susan.
Hello, Jen. Please take our programming language poll.
Thanks for taking the poll Jeff.
etc.
```

I have tried

```
for name, language in respondents.items():
    if name.lower() in respondents.keys() == name.lower() in class_mates:
      print("\nThanks for taking the poll",name.title())
    else:
        print("Hello,",name.title()+". Please take our programming language poll."
```

Whenever I run this it just prints the else statement for every match in respondents.
If anyone can enlighten me to what I'm doing wrong,
and point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to iterate over the wrong iterable, and also trying to check if there were lower case names in class_mates which is always going to return false.

Comment: if the issue is addressed, please close the question.